# Create an inline object and pass as parameter

Tags: java, c++, parameters, inline, new-operator

Hi I come from Java where the following is valid:

```
System.out.println(new String("Hello World"));
```

is there a C++ equivalent to passing creating an object or pointer in the constructor and pass it as a parameter at the same time such as.

```
heap.insert(new Food);
```

Comment: Thank you guys. In this specific example, I did new because the function required a pointer. If anyone in the future needs help the answers below work; however, if a pointer is needed it's done this way.

    myObject.insert(  (new Object2(parameters))  );
If the new statement is not in parenthesis the code will fail I don't really know why but it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example

```
std::vector<Food> c;
c.emplace_back(constructor arguments for Food);
```

In general, it is most often the case that objects are not given to method as pointers.

If `heap.insert` takes a const reference :

```
void insert(const Food& val);
```

then you can use it with temporary or existing Food arguments, such as

```
heap.insert(Food{});

var auto foo = Food{constructor arguments};
heap.insert(foo);
heap.insert(Food(constructor arguments));
```

or in some cases even

```
heap.insert({constructor arguments});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have to define a class, a constructor for it that accepts parameters, then a function that accepts instances of that class and that's all.

Eventually, add to the class definition a proper copy constructor or pass it by reference.

It follows an example:

```
struct S {
    S(int x) { this->x = x; }
    int x;
};

void fn(S s) { }
void cfn(const S &s) { }

int main() {
    fn(S{42});
    cfn(S{42});
}
```

Be aware that using `new` in such a case is one of the easiest ways to incur in a memory leak, so pay attention!!

Answer (score 2):

The examples you gave are too easy.

```
cout << string("hello World");
// not necessary to contruct a string, but to show that it can be done on the spot

heap.insert(Food()); // construct a Food on the spot...
```

But in general, if you are talking about anonymous classes and similar things in Java, C++ has this stuff, and it has also the *lambda* concept which is very powerful ;)

Comment: Java's got Lambdas also now

Comment: @JohanLundberg fine, I did not say Java doesnt have them. It seemed to me that the essence of the OP's question was about these concepts. Answer is yes, I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
heap.insert(new Food);
```

in of itself is valid C++ syntax. It constructs a new instance of the `Food` class, and passes it to heap's insert() method.

However, the key fundamental difference you will need to learn when transitioning from Java to C++ is that your C++ application is completely responsible for managing all object's lifetimes. In Java you don't need to think about it. Once an object is no longer referenced anywhere, at some point it'll get destroyed by Java's garbage collector.

C++ makes you responsible for managing each object's lifetime. Whenever your application does not need the object that you constructed here with the `new` operator, it should be `delete`d, otherwise you're going to leak memory.

To summarize:

```
heap.insert(new Food);
```

is just half the story. The `new` operator will construct your new class instance, and your `heap` object's insert() method, presumably, stores the pointer to the new class instance, in some fashion. Somewhere, you will then need to `delete` that class instance, sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

If the function parameter is by value or by const reference, and the type you are passing can be used to construct the object, you can pass it directly. For example:

```
void print(const std::string& str);

int main()
{
    print("Hello world");
}
```

`std::string` has a constructor which can accept the string literal, and therefore the code compiles, creating a temporary string object, equivalent to:

```
print(std::string("Hello world"));
```

If the constructor takes multiple parameters, you can create a temporary object directly in the function call. For example:

```
void myfunc(const MyClass& c);

myfunc(MyClass(param1, param2));
```

In Java new objects are creating using `new`. In C++, `new` is not required to create a new object, and should be avoided as much as possible, because it makes it harder to avoid memory leaks. This is one of the most common mistakes programmers coming from Java make.

```
std::string text;
MyClass c;
c.do_something();
```

This code is totally valid. `text` and `c` are valid objects.

```
std::string *text = new std::string();
MyClass *c = new MyClass();
c->do_something();
delete text;
delete c;
```

This code is also valid*. But it takes more typing, and if you forget to delete them, you will get a memory leak.

*Edit: Actually it is not exception safe! All the more reason to avoid `new`!